# How to remove some item based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting all file upload control through the following code

```
   var fileuploadControls = $( "input[type='file']" );
```

Now I want to loop thorugh the fileuploadControls  and remove if ID is not matching something like this

```
for(var i=0;i<fileuploadControls .length;++i)
 {
       if(fileuploadControls[i].id != "A")
        {
          //remove the item and fileUploadcontrols should be same type of abject as returned by the jquery not an array
         }

 }
```

I have tried splice it works but it returns an array which I don't want after removal of item fileuploadControls  should of same type of object as it was before removal only one item should be less

Can someone help in coding this

I am using  the following celltemplate in Angular ui-grid

```
 cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"> <input name="curfewRegularizationFile"  id="curfewRegularizationFile" type="file" class="k-state-disabled"  /></div>',
```

and in javascript file I am doing this

```
  fileuploadControls[i].kendoUpload({ // Do something as per kendo});
```

Comment: `fileuploadControls[i].remove()` doesn't work?

Comment: Not working I tried just now

Comment: `$(fileuploadControls[i]).remove()`

Comment: @ShaunakD, don't do this! It's slow and bad, to recast it again in an jQuery object. ;) `fileuploadControls.eq(i).remove()`

Comment: @eisbehr, user already has `fileuploadControls[i]` object available. So it won't matter.

Comment: Yes, but his code is even not good. And yes, but he don't cast it. He only use the count so far.

Comment: @eisbehr    fileuploadControls.eq(i).remove() works but it removes the control from the document too I want only fileuploadControls to be modified  not document object

Comment: You didn't say that. Use `fileuploadControls =  fileuploadControls.not("#A")` then as example. No loop needed then.

Comment: @rajib dey your code do not work because fileuploadControls[i] will turn out to be a dom object instead of a jquery one.

Comment: Can you please post HTML

Comment: Or if you already know what you don't need, you can change you initial selector: `var fileuploadControls = $("input[type='file']:not(#A)");`

Comment: @super-cool-handsome-gel-boy   Yes got it so I am trying a workaround actually I want to transafor some into kendo control so I am doing other way looping matching the id and then calling kendo function instead of all dom object

Comment: @eisbehr I know the selector so anyway I can specify only to select those file upload control with specific id

Comment: Plus, you cannot have more than 1 element with same id

Comment: @superCool What if it is inside grid and we put id then ID are repeating right

Comment: ID's never ever repeat! They are uniqe!

Comment: Then the javascript will cause problems. Use class instead please, don't use ids.

Comment: Back to the inital question. I've edited my answer and show you many ways to do it now. Something should match your needs! ;)

Comment: ind grid id are repting how do u handle without id of a control inside grid

Comment: I will repeat myself: IDs are uniqe! If they repeat, your html is wrong! That is a fact. IDs should never repeat. Use classes then, if you need a multiple identifier.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove from DOM too:**

In your loop you can do it this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fileuploadControls.length; ++i ) {
    if( fileuploadControls[i].id !== "A" )
        fileuploadControls.eq(i).remove();
}
```

But I would do it in the jQuery way, in a loop with jQuery objects you can do it with `each`. But this is even the slowest option to choose.

```
fileuploadControls.each(function() {
    if( $(this).attr("id") !== "A" )
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Or directly as a sub-selector:

```
fileuploadControls.not("#A").remove();
```

---

**Remove only from Object:**

By better initial selector:

```
var fileuploadControls = $("input[type=file]:not(#A)");
```

By trim down the jQuery object:

```
fileuploadControls = fileuploadControls.not("#A");
```

By filter:

```
fileuploadControls =  fileuploadControls.filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id") !== "A";
});
```

Comment: I need the fileuploadControls with dom objects whose ID are "#A" and input tye as file and A will be repeating  how can I do it

Comment: Multiple people already told you, that IDs are not repeating, they are uniqe. Please review your code, if they are repeating. Use classe instead or post your code in a question here on SO, and let them give you the help you need.

Comment: I have edited the code and included the HTML and js part if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can can create a function to remove element

```
for(var i=0;i<fileuploadControls .length;++i)
 {
       if(fileuploadControls[i].id != "A")
        {
            remove(fileuploadControls[i].id);
        }

 }

function remove(id) {
    return (el=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```